# SpotLight Rotation in three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to rotate a spotlight. My code is:

```
var light   = new THREE.SpotLight( color, intensity, distance );
light.position.set( 0, 100, 0 );
light.rotation.set( 0, Math.PI, 0 );
light.shadowCameraFar = 50;
light.shadowCameraNear      = 0.01;     
light.castShadow        = true;
light.shadowDarkness        = 0.5;
light.shadowCameraVisible   = true;
light.shadowCameraFar = 800;
light.shadowCameraFov = 15;
scene.add( light );
```

I want to know what I'm doing wrong. The spotlight doesn't change its rotation independent the value I put.

Answer (score 4):

`light.target` determines the spotlight's shadow camera orientation. If, for example, you have an object in your scene called myObject, you could do something like this:

```
light.target = myObject;
```

Remember, `light.target` is an `Object3D`, not a position vector.

Three.js r.49

Comment: This works when you do `light.target = camera`, however I can't get it to work on a mesh or an object

Answer (score 3):

So you would position the light target either by direct assignment:

```
myLight.target.position = new THREE.Object3D( 10, 20, 30 );
```

Or by defining the light target object properties:

```
myLight.target.position.x = 10;
myLight.target.position.y = 20;
myLight.target.position.z = 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add a empty Object3D into SpotLight as a child

```
const targetObject = new THREE.Object3D()
scene.add(targetObject)
spotLight.add(targetObject)
targetObject.position.set(0,-1,0)
spotLight.target = targetObject
```

and then you just control spotLight's rotation

Comment: Nice one, but why add targetObject first to scene then  to spotLight? I think line 2 is unnecessary.

Comment: line 2 is to put targetObject as a child of spotLight so that the rotation value of spotLight will automatically rotate target as well, changing the subject of the rotation to target -> spotLight.